# SQL And Drupal skips admin set up

Tags: database, installation

I filled out the Database name, Database username, password, and port number within the Drupal set up. I selected continue, then the page loads for a long time. Next, I was leaded to another page saying, Drupal already installed. Next, I clicked on View your existing site, displaying the log in for the admin. Drupal literally skipped the admin set up, resulting in not allowing me to log in as admin. Anyone is familiar with this error? Is this even an error, or the norm for Drupal (since I seen other users experiencing this errors, but no answers)?

Drupal explain the the error is the following

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
>   Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException: Configuration objects
>   (automated_cron.settings, block.block.bartik_account_menu,
>   block.block.bartik_branding, block.block.bartik_breadcrumbs,
>   block.block.bartik_content..

If anyone that knows this, feel free to provide some input.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking a lot of questions at the same time, but I assume your main question is *How to recover from this failed installation?*

You are seeing an `UnmetDependenciesException`, which means Drupal requires stuff (has a dependency) that has not been loaded... So probably several system modules did not install properly.

That would also explain the behavior you are experiencing, your Drupal installation is broken...

Best would be to start over from scratch, remove all the files and the database tables and try again. Also verify if you have met all of the [web server requirements (Drupal 7 & 8)](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/system-requirements/overview).

Comment: Thanks, however all files are loaded according to the tutorial (there is only one tutorial on the internet that displays how to connect sql with drupal)  http://www.drupalonwindows.com/en/blog/installing-drupal-8-windows . Therefore this has to be either drupal, or microsoft driver itself. Strange enough, on Chrome, it went from the page saying "already installed" to the install bar, installing, however when I re did it, I was unable to get to the install bar (unable to install again). Basically Drupal and MSSQL is broken. Otherwise, it would work.